# Get a specific service implementation based on a parameter

Tags: osgi, sling

In my Sling app I have data presenting documents, with pages, and content nodes. We mostly server those documents as HTML, but now I would like to have a servlet to serve these documents as PDF and PPT.

Basically, I thought about implementing the factory pattern : in my servlet, dependending on the extension of the request (pdf or ppt), I would get from a DocumentBuilderFactory, the proper DocumentBuilder implementation, either PdfDocumentBuilder or PptDocumentBuilder.

So first I had this:

```
public class PlanExportBuilderFactory {

  public PlanExportBuilder getBuilder(String type) {
    PlanExportBuilder builder = null;
    switch (type) {
      case "pdf":
        builder = new PdfPlanExportBuilder();
        break;
      default: 
        logger.error("Unsupported plan export builder, type: " + type);
    }
    return builder;
  }
}
```

In the servlet:

```
@Component(metatype = false)
@Service(Servlet.class)
@Properties({ 
  @Property(name = "sling.servlet.resourceTypes", value = "myApp/document"), 
  @Property(name = "sling.servlet.extensions", value = { "ppt", "pdf" }),
  @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = "GET") 
})
public class PlanExportServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

  @Reference
  PlanExportBuilderFactory builderFactory;

  @Override
  protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Resource resource = request.getResource();

    PlanExportBuilder builder = builderFactory.getBuilder(request.getRequestPathInfo().getExtension());
  }
}
```

But the problem is that in the builder I would like to reference other services to access Sling resources, and with this solution, they're not bound.

I looked at Services Factory with OSGi but from what I've understood, you use them to configure differently the same implementation of a service.

Then I found that you can get a specific implementation by naming it, or use a property and a filter.

So I've ended up with this:

```
public class PlanExportBuilderFactory {

  @Reference(target = "(builderType=pdf)")
  PlanExportBuilder pdfPlanExportBuilder;

  public PlanExportBuilder getBuilder(String type) {
    PlanExportBuilder builder = null;
    switch (type) {
      case "pdf":
        return pdfPlanExportBuilder;
      default: 
        logger.error("Unsupported plan export builder, type: " + type);
    }
    return builder;
  }

}
```

The builder defining a "builderType" property :

```
// AbstractPlanExportBuilder implements PlanExportBuilder interface
@Component
@Service(value=PlanExportBuilder.class)
public class PdfPlanExportBuilder extends AbstractPlanExportBuilder {

  @Property(name="builderType", value="pdf")

  public PdfPlanExportBuilder() {
    planDocument = new PdfPlanDocument();
  }
}
```

I would like to know if it's a good way to retrieve my PDF builder implementation regarding OSGi good practices.

**EDIT 1**

From Peter's answer I've tried to add multiple references but with Felix it doesn't seem to work:

```
 @Reference(name = "planExportBuilder", cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_MULTIPLE, policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC)
private Map<String, PlanExportBuilder> builders = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, PlanExportBuilder>();

protected final void bindPlanExportBuilder(PlanExportBuilder b, Map<String, Object> props) {
  final String type = PropertiesUtil.toString(props.get("type"), null);
  if (type != null) {
    this.builders.put((String) props.get("type"), b);
  }
}

protected final void unbindPlanExportBuilder(final PlanExportBuilder b, Map<String, Object> props) {
  final String type = PropertiesUtil.toString(props.get("type"), null);
  if (type != null) {
    this.builders.remove(type);
  }
}
```

I get these errors :

```
@Reference(builders) : Missing method bind for reference planExportBuilder
@Reference(builders) : Something went wrong: false - true - MANDATORY_MULTIPLE
@Reference(builders) : Missing method unbind for reference planExportBuilder
```

The Felix documentation here http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html#reference says for the bind method:

> The default value is the name created by appending the reference name to the string bind. The method must be declared public or protected and take single argument which is declared with the service interface type

So according to this, I understand it cannot work with Felix, as I'm trying to pass two arguments. However, I found an example here that seems to match what you've suggested but I cannot make it work: https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/services/impl/SampleMultiReferenceServiceImpl.java

**EDIT 2**
Just had to move the reference above the class to make it work:

```
@References({
  @Reference(
    name = "planExportBuilder",
    referenceInterface = PlanExportBuilder.class,
    policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,
    cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL_MULTIPLE)
})
public class PlanExportServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factories are evil :-) Main reason is of course the yucky class loading hacks that are usually used but also because they tend to have global knowledge. In general, you want to be able to add a bundle with a new DocumentBuilder and then that type should become available.

A more OSGi oriented solution is therefore to use service properties. This could look like:

```
@Component( property=HTTP_WHITEBOARD_FILTER_REGEX+"=/as")
public class DocumentServlet {

  final Map<String,DocBuilder>        builders = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public void doGet( HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rsp ) 
                           throws IOException, ServletException {

    InputStream in = getInputStream( rq.getPathInfo() );
    if ( in == null ) 
      ....

    String type = toType( rq.getPathInfo(), rq.getParameter("type") );

    DocBuilder docbuilder = builders.get( type );
    if ( docbuilder == null)
       ....

    docbuilder.convert( type, in, rsp.getOutputStream() );
 }

 @Reference( cardinality=MULTIPLE, policy=DYNAMIC )
 void addDocBuilder( DocBuilder db, Map<String,Object> props ) {
    docbuilders.put(props.get("type"), db );
 }

 void removeDocBuilder(Map<String,Object> props ) {
    docbuilders.remove(props.get("type"));
 }
```

}

A DocBuilder could look like:

```
@Component( property = "type=ppt-pdf" )
public class PowerPointToPdf implements DocBuilder {
    ...
}
```

Comment: When you say "Factories are evil" you mean specifically in an OSGi context? Our application is small and therefore all code is packaged in a single bundle for now, but I'll try your solution, thank you.

Comment: I dislike Java factories because they are 'global' variables, tend to use class loading 'hacks' that wreak havoc on modularity principles, and require that the one needing an object takes the initiative. The OSGi service model allows a party to register a fully initialized object with its own context. This is a broker model and is much more powerful imho.

Comment: I have tried to implement what you've suggested but I cannot make it work, I've edited my question. It cannot find the bind and unbind methods. Also, I've realized that transforming my document builder into an OSGi service will make it a singleton, which won't work with the Builder pattern implementation. Is there a possibility to get services references into a class that is not a service itself?

Comment: Just make your DocBuilder a DocBuilderBuilder service. I am not sure why you can't get the pseudo code to work, it is pretty simple DS?

Comment: I just had to move the reference into @References above the class declaration, that is actually what was done in the Adobe example. I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "Just make your DocBuilder a DocBuilderBuilder service"? Is it to generate different services instance for my PdfDocBuilder and be able to get other services references with getting rid of the singleton problem?

Comment: @Reference above class sounds very wrong? (If you want to know more about DS, look at OSGi enRoute tutorials.) Since you stated that your DocBuilder must not be a singleton, you just make it a service that can build DocBuilder objects, i.e. a factory. Since you get the factory as service this is ok because it does not require the awkward Java class loading hacks that plague classic Java factories.

Comment: I didn't know it was wrong, I've seen that many times in the Sling source codes for instance. I've read OSGi enRoute, but it seems some things differ from Felix implementation. For the second point, if I create DocBuilderBuilder, I will get DocBuilder objects that are not OSGi component, then I won't be able to access SOGiServices from them, am I right? That was my first goal, access other OSGi services from a DocBuilder class, which cannot be an OSGi services as I store object on it (following the pattern) and then cannot be a singleton.

Comment: Maybe the main question would be something like "How can I inject OSGi services in a non OSGi class?" or "How can I have a new instance of my OSGi component each time I call it?". Because for now, I don't see how to implement the Builder pattern in an OSGi context.

Comment: I finally used setters to access my services in the builder.